# How to edit/delete a .dot_file on mac without using Terminal

Tags: bash, osx, editors

When I start Terminal I can not control it. It starts executing an endless loop repeating that `some alias` does not exist. Because of this I am not able to edit this file using a program such as `vim`. Is there a way to update/delete `.bash_profile` and do not use Terminal at all, providing I have a replacement `.bash_profile`?.

Comment: What is `some alias`, exactly? Also, try doing cntrl-c (or the mac equivalent) that is frequently used on Windows/Linux to terminate a running command. It should free up your Terminal.

Comment: I have put `source` after my custom alias. doing `ctrl + c` and opening new terminal does not help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to open hidden files, even if normally they are not shown in **Finder**. You can edit `.bash_profile` and comment out the lines that are causing problems or just delete everything to make the entire file empty.

1. Open a plain text editor, for example **TextEdit**
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
3. Navigate to your home directory
4. If you don't see `.bash_profile`, then press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files (on my US keyboard layout, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> is actually <kbd>></kbd>, so perhaps the *real* shortcut is actually <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>)
5. Select `.bash_profile`, fix the problem, and save it

Comment: Tried this just now on macOS 10.15.1 and did not work. The shortcut nowadays appears to be `cmd+shift+.` (last character is period).

Comment: Thanks @basse, that might actually be the same thing. I edited my post to clarify.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now that I think of it, the period probably applies to my Finnish kb layout and some other non-US layouts.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> should allow you to terminate the misbehaving process and return a responsive shell prompt in most cases. Please note on the Mac that I am referring to the <kbd>Control</kbd> key, NOT the <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

Comment: protip: enclose keyboard shortcuts in `<kbd>` tags, and they'll be formatted all pretty.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to solving your problem is to change your shell temporarily. To do this, go into Terminal's preferences. Change the option "shells open with" to "command" instead of "login shell". In the path box, type the name of some other shell on your system that has config files that aren't hosed. Since you're using `bash`, `/bin/zsh` might be a nice option.

Open a new terminal. You may now edit your files.

To get back to `bash`, simply change the "shells open with" option back to "login shell".

Answer (score 0):

You could also save a new file that overwrites .bash_profile. Sublime Text allowed saving a file with a . in front of the name (albeit, with a few warnings).